# SFDC Advanced Visual workflow loop optimization

Tags: flow, visual-workflow, sobject

I am trying to do a   **conditional, multi-level deep clone** based on a hierarchy of template records.

The conditional part means that if the target record exists, then I do not update/overwrite it. I am doing the "Is Exists?" inside a loop and now getting error Too many Queries: 101 governor limit.

The flow works just fine if the number of records in the tree is small.

I am doing the Create in Bulk so that is part fine.
Can't figure out an equivalent of a Map<> that I can use in flow or
a equivalent of SOQL IN Clause or any other way to avoid putting the query (lookup) inside the loop.

[image: Error happens at Fast Lookup element]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am afraid you can not do it (can not use WHERE id IN collection variable). That's a reason to try to use apex invocable -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

Comment: Thanks! for confirming. I was hoping there was something I was missing and I could avoid apex (and test classes) but looks like code it is.

Comment: Anytime you run a DML in a loop, you will probably hit this error. All lookups, updates, creates and deletes should be avoiding inside a loop to prevent hitting max queries. It's almost a sure thing if you do.

Comment: Hi markross__c, exactly, trying to get the query out of loop. any idea on how to do that in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 alternatives of avoiding too many soql queries in a flow, and without using Apex.

1. You can try using the **Wait** element.
2. Or a not so useful but an option that works is to introduce another **screen** in the loop.  This splits the transaction.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: SfdcFanBoy, do you know if Wait element only adds a delay or does it create a new execution flow and context? If latter then I can get increased governor limits.

Comment: It starts a new transaction.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out the Wait element and looks like the min duration for that is 1 hour, so I guess I need to go the Apex route.